# Crear diccionario a partir de archivo .csv en Python 3, de 2 columnas, donde una fila sean los valores y la otra las llaves

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, diccionarios

Tengo un archivo .csv con datos de este estilo y busco convertirlo a un diccionario, donde la primera fila sirva de llave y la segunda fila sirva de valor

```
df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")

df.head(5)

CLAVE MUNICIPIO
 1     AHOME
 2     El FUERTE
 3     CHOIX
 4     ANGOSTURA
 5     SALVADOR ALVARADO
```

Lo que busco es que el resultado se vea así (puedo eliminar la fila con el nombre de las columnas de manera manual, si no hay forma de automatizarlo).

```
diccionario = {1: "AHOME", 2: "EL FUERTE", 3: "CHOIX", 4: "ANGOSTURA", 5: "SALVADOR ALVARADO"}
```

Para resolver el problema he utilizado el método pd.to_dict(), pero me devuelve un diccionario con los nombres de las columnas como llaves y los valores como un diccionario dentro del diccionario, con los diferentes valores de las filas

```
nuevo_dict = pd.to_dict(df)
nuevo_dict = {'CLAVE: {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5}, 
'MUNICIPIO': {0: "AHOME, 1: "EL FUERTE", 
2: "CHOIX", 3: "ANGOSTURA, 
4: "SALVADOR ALVARADO}}
```

He leído la documentación del método y lamentablemente no hay manera en que pueda devolverme el resultado deseado, por lo que busco una manera de lograr el resultado indicado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo un CSV con la estructura:

> CLAVE,MUNICIPIO
>   1,HOME
>   2,El FUERTE
>   3,CHOIX
>   4,ANGOSTURA
>   5,SALVADOR ALVARADO

Yo no usaría Pandas si al final solo quieres el diccionario, usa simplemente el módulo `csv` de la stdlib será más eficiente en este caso:

```
import csv

with open("archivo.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # Descartamos cabecera
    nuevo_dict = dict(reader)
```

Si quieres que la clave sea un entero, cambia `nuevo_dict = dict(reader)` por:

```
nuevo_dict = {int(clave): municipio for clave, municipio in reader}
```

la salida sería:

> ```
> {1: 'HOME', 2: 'El FUERTE', 3: 'CHOIX', 4: 'ANGOSTURA', 5: 'SALVADOR ALVARADO'}
> ```

Si aún así quieres usar Pandas, `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` no te vale para lo que buscas, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")
nuevo_dict = dict(zip(df["CLAVE"], df["MUNICIPIO"]))
```

Pero te obliga a crear un DataFrame en memoria que, a no ser que lo uses para algo más, es completamente innecesario e ineficiente comparado con la primera opción.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me quedo con la opción del módulo csv, sin duda.